# xpath:how to use parent element

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to know how to choose parent node in xpath?
beacuse the structure of the website is not fixed.
sometimes it will show location then phone ,sometimes phone first than location
so I can't use `li[1] li[2]`
My thought is to know the `p.title/text()` contains 'location' first
If it is 'location',then choose its ancestor `<div class="row">`
then find the `<p><span class="add">LA</span></p>`

In brief,I want to know how to use xpath to choose 'LA' ?
But don't use the method `sel.xpath("li[1]/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-xs-8']/p/text()")`
Please guide me thank you

```
<li>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p class="title">location</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <p><span class="add">LA</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p class="title">phone</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <p><span class="phone">123456789</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly multiple ways to write xpath here.

One option is to start with `div` with `row` class, check that the first div contains `p` tag with `location` text and get the `span` tag that is inside `p` that is inside the second `div`:

```
//div[@class = "row" and div[1]/p[@class="title" and text() = "location"]]/div[2]/p/span/text()
```

Demo (using [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class = "row" and div[1]/p[@class="title" and text() = "location"]]/div[2]/p/span/text()').extract()
[u'LA']
```

Comment: Wow! It's really awesome!! Thank you very much.I didn't know code can be wrote like this way before you show me!